# Accounts Receivable Query: with CASE, PARTITION BY and WHERE

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have used a previous Stack example to get started but I am having trouble SUMing the totals of the data. Sorry it is long but it is all relevant.

```
SELECT DISTINCT         TRIM(RMCUST.REP_CODE) AS 'Rep',
                        RMCUST.CUST_NAME AS 'Customer',
                        FORMAT(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(DD, RMDET.TRAN_DATE, GETDATE()) <= 30
                        THEN SUM(RMDET.TRAN_AMT)
                        OVER (PARTITION BY RMCUST.CUST_NAME)
                        ELSE 0
                        END, 'c') AS '0 - 30',
                        FORMAT(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(DD, RMDET.TRAN_DATE, GETDATE()) > 30 AND DATEDIFF(DD, RMDET.TRAN_DATE, GETDATE()) <= 60
                        THEN SUM(RMDET.TRAN_AMT)
                        OVER (PARTITION BY RMCUST.CUST_NAME)
                        ELSE 0
                        END, 'c') AS '31 - 60',
                        FORMAT(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(DD, RMDET.TRAN_DATE, GETDATE()) > 60 AND DATEDIFF(DD, RMDET.TRAN_DATE, GETDATE()) <= 90
                        THEN SUM(RMDET.TRAN_AMT)
                        OVER (PARTITION BY RMCUST.CUST_NAME)
                        ELSE 0
                        END, 'c') AS '61 - 90',
                        FORMAT(CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(DD, RMDET.TRAN_DATE, GETDATE()) > 90
                        THEN SUM(RMDET.TRAN_AMT)
                        OVER (PARTITION BY RMCUST.CUST_NAME)
                        ELSE 0
                        END, 'c') AS '>90'      
FROM                    RMDET (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN              RMCUST (NOLOCK) ON RMCUST.CUST_CODE = RMDET.CUST_CODE
WHERE                   RMDET.TRAN_AMT_APPLIED = 0
GROUP BY                RMCUST.REP_CODE, RMCUST.CUST_NAME, RMDET.TRAN_DATE, RMDET.TRAN_AMT
ORDER BY                RMCUST.CUST_NAME
```

Output:

```
Rep Customer                        0 - 30     31 - 60  61 - 90    >90
------------------------------------------------------------------------
KG  135 PRIME                       $0.00       $0.00   $462.66    $0.00
AS  71 ABOVE                        $2,469.60   $0.00   $0.00      $0.00
KH  ABERNETHYS MUSIC CENTER         $0.00       $0.00   $1,014.60  $0.00
KH  ABERNETHYS MUSIC CENTER         $1,014.60   $0.00   $0.00      $0.00
BH  AC HOTEL                        $132.28     $0.00   $0.00      $0.00
AS  ACE HOTEL                       $0.00       $0.00   $0.00      ($0.91)
AS  AKASHA                          $0.00       $0.00   $12,052.06 $0.00
AS  AKASHA                          $0.00       $12,052.06  $0.00  $0.00
AS  AKASHA                          $12,052.06  $0.00   $0.00      $0.00
```

Here is the raw data from the table. The query is putting the total owed in all columns when it should show only one row with the different totals for each column depending on the date. Where am I going wrong? Thank you.

```
Rep Customer                        Date     Invoice #  0 - 30 31 - 60  61 - 90 >90
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
KG  135 PRIME                       12/20/2019  870     $0.00   $0.00   $462.66 $0.00
AS  71 ABOVE                        02/14/2020  5240    $397.60 $0.00   $0.00   $0.00
AS  71 ABOVE                        02/15/2020  5341    $978.60 $0.00   $0.00   $0.00
AS  71 ABOVE                        02/17/2020  5423    $427.00 $0.00   $0.00   $0.00
AS  71 ABOVE                        02/18/2020  5529    $509.60 $0.00   $0.00   $0.00
AS  71 ABOVE                        02/19/2020  5608    $156.80 $0.00   $0.00   $0.00
KH  ABERNETHYS MUSIC CENTER         12/19/2019  721     $0.00   $0.00   $450.50 $0.00
KH  ABERNETHYS MUSIC CENTER         02/19/2020  5657    $180.20 $0.00   $0.00   $0.00
KH  ABERNETHYS MUSIC CENTER         12/05/2019  235884  $0.00   $0.00   $383.90 $0.00
BH  AC HOTEL                        02/13/2020  5181    $30.21  $0.00   $0.00   $0.00
BH  AC HOTEL                        02/18/2020  5593    $102.07 $0.00   $0.00   $0.00
AS  ACE HOTEL                       03/14/2018  193386  $0.00   $0.00   $0.00   ($0.72)
AS  ACE HOTEL                       04/30/2018  CREDITS-09  $0.00   $0.00   $0.00   ($0.19)
AS  AKASHA                          01/02/2020  1789    $0.00   $128.70 $0.00   $0.00
AS  AKASHA                          01/04/2020  1959    $0.00   $223.37 $0.00   $0.00
AS  AKASHA                          01/07/2020  2141    $0.00   $161.95 $0.00   $0.00
AS  AKASHA                          01/08/2020  2218    $0.00   $102.00 $0.00   $0.00
AS  AKASHA                          01/09/2020  2326    $0.00   $444.00 $0.00   $0.00
AS  AKASHA                          01/10/2020  2416    $0.00   $596.82 $0.00   $0.00
AS  AKASHA                          01/11/2020  2531    $0.00   $462.11 $0.00   $0.00
AS  AKASHA                          01/14/2020  2701    $0.00   $303.10 $0.00   $0.00
AS  AKASHA                          01/16/2020  2879    $0.00   $804.24 $0.00   $0.00
AS  AKASHA                          01/17/2020  2989    $0.00   $442.11 $0.00   $0.00
AS  AKASHA                          01/18/2020  3080    $0.00   $95.47  $0.00   $0.00
AS  AKASHA                          01/20/2020  3181    $225.86 $0.00   $0.00   $0.00
AS  AKASHA                          01/22/2020  3366    $145.02 $0.00   $0.00   $0.00
AS  AKASHA                          01/23/2020  3451    $126.42 $0.00   $0.00   $0.00
AS  AKASHA                          01/24/2020  3544    $510.90 $0.00   $0.00   $0.00
AS  AKASHA                          01/25/2020  3656    $227.76 $0.00   $0.00   $0.00
AS  AKASHA                          01/27/2020  3733    $156.88 $0.00   $0.00   $0.00
AS  AKASHA                          01/29/2020  3914    $264.37 $0.00   $0.00   $0.00
AS  AKASHA                          01/30/2020  4006    $705.27 $0.00   $0.00   $0.00
AS  AKASHA                          01/31/2020  4106    $184.20 $0.00   $0.00   $0.00
AS  AKASHA                          02/01/2020  4222    $180.30 $0.00   $0.00   $0.00
AS  AKASHA                          02/04/2020  4387    $209.59 $0.00   $0.00   $0.00
AS  AKASHA                          02/05/2020  4462    $259.76 $0.00   $0.00   $0.00
AS  AKASHA                          02/06/2020  4572    $276.91 $0.00   $0.00   $0.00
AS  AKASHA                          02/07/2020  4666    $558.18 $0.00   $0.00   $0.00
AS  AKASHA                          02/08/2020  4782    $249.31 $0.00   $0.00   $0.00
AS  AKASHA                          02/11/2020  4866    $395.93 $0.00   $0.00   $0.00
AS  AKASHA                          02/13/2020  5108    $467.89 $0.00   $0.00   $0.00
AS  AKASHA                          02/14/2020  5220    $125.63 $0.00   $0.00   $0.00
AS  AKASHA                          02/15/2020  5367    $173.64 $0.00   $0.00   $0.00
AS  AKASHA                          02/17/2020  5449    $355.40 $0.00   $0.00   $0.00
AS  AKASHA                          02/18/2020  5548    $220.65 $0.00   $0.00   $0.00
AS  AKASHA                          02/19/2020  5636    $608.92 $0.00   $0.00   $0.00
AS  AKASHA                          12/04/2019  235786  $0.00   $0.00   $299.46 $0.00
AS  AKASHA                          12/04/2019  235806  $0.00   $0.00   $150.18 $0.00
AS  AKASHA                          12/06/2019  236042  $0.00   $0.00   $954.18 $0.00
AS  AKASHA                          12/07/2019  236108  $0.00   $0.00   $310.82 $0.00
AS  AKASHA                          12/10/2019  236300  $0.00   $0.00   $70.50  $0.00
AS  AKASHA                          12/31/2019  CREDITS-08  $0.00   ($125.74)   $0.00   $0.00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this just using `GROUP BY` and `CASE` without needing to use window functions:

```
select
    c.rep_code,
    c.cust_name,
    sum(case when datediff(day,d.tran_date,getdate()) <= 30             then d.tran_amt else 0 end) as [0 - 30],
    sum(case when datediff(day,d.tran_date,getdate()) between 31 and 60 then d.tran_amt else 0 end) as [31 - 60],
    sum(case when datediff(day,d.tran_date,getdate()) between 61 and 90 then d.tran_amt else 0 end) as [61 - 90],
    sum(case when datediff(day,d.tran_date,getdate()) > 90              then d.tran_amt else 0 end) as [>90]
from rmdet d
join rmcust c on d.cust_code = c.cust_code
group by
    c.rep_code,
    c.cust_name
order by c.cust_name
```

Results:

```
/--------------------------------------------------------------------------\
| rep_code |        cust_name        | 0 - 30  | 31 - 60 | 61 - 90 |  >90  |
|----------|-------------------------|---------|---------|---------|-------|
|    KG    |        135 PRIME        |    0.00 |    0.00 |  462.66 |  0.00 |
|    AS    |        71 ABOVE         | 2469.60 |    0.00 |    0.00 |  0.00 |
|    KH    | ABERNETHYS MUSIC CENTER |  180.20 |    0.00 |  834.40 |  0.00 |
|    BH    |        AC HOTEL         |  132.28 |    0.00 |    0.00 |  0.00 |
|    AS    |        ACE HOTEL        |    0.00 |    0.00 |    0.00 | -0.91 |
|    AS    |         AKASHA          | 6402.93 | 3863.99 | 1785.14 |  0.00 |
\--------------------------------------------------------------------------/
```

Comment: This is fantastic thank you! I was over complicating it! Much appreciated

Comment: No worries, thanks for the upvote and accept, glad it helped.